# what is the calculation for converting px/em/rem to vw in 100vw(100% width)?

Tags: css

[image]

What is the calculation for converting 45px/45em/45rem to vw in 100vw(100% width)? Can it be done with css?

```css
font-size:calc(calculation for 45px to vw in 100vw);

font-size:calc(calculation for 45em to vw in 100vw);

font-size:calc(calculation for 45rem to vw in 100vw);
```

Comment: It can be done using JAVASCRIPT.

Comment: why not change the font-size depending upon the resolution of the device using media property of css as follows, default .text { font-size: 2rem } @media (max-width: 960px ) {  .text { font-size: 1rem }  } try to know more about media queries in css it would be of greatly help

Comment: What does that mean? Should the font size scale with the viewport width or not?

Comment: @Ry, yes. It should.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.ha{
 font-size: calc(100vw / 45);
}
```

```html
<a class='ha'>Hello World</a>
```

The `calc()` function performs a calculation to be used as the property value.

*To calculate the vw we can divide 100vw to your requried px.*

> 1px = (100vw / [document.documentElement.clientWidth] px)
>
> e.g. — If your viewport was 500px wide (equals by definition to 100vw) then

> viewport width = (100vw / 45px) = 2.2vw

Comment: your answer worked on 45px but on others I am having problem. For a quickview here is the link. https://codepen.io/alrahat/pen/ZEEvXjN

Comment: request button is 18px, login/sign up is 16px and menu is 15.5px.

Comment: check the image. I want the top and menu area like the image above.

Comment: Got it. just add * 1px, inside of calc. after your division like this.font-size:calc(100vw / 15.5 * 1px); because the problem is with calc(100vw / 15.5) you will just get a number without an unit. CSS can't display just a number as width. This would be like if you set width: 5.5 which obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the calculation formulas:

```
PX: px / viewport total width * 100
REM: ((rem * rem size) / vw) * 100
EM: ((em * em size) / vw) * 100
```

Here you can see more info about them:

PX: https://cssunitconverter.vercel.app/px-to-vw#faq

REM: https://cssunitconverter.vercel.app/rem-to-vw#faq

EM: https://cssunitconverter.vercel.app/em-to-vw#faq

P.S. By the way REM and EM calculation logic is the same I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed that :)